# Another job is executed in the spring batch with job.names

Tags: spring, spring-batch

i have two Job like that ..

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class A1 {
  private final JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
  ...

  @Bean
  public Job test1() {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("test1").start(step()).build();
  }

  ... step, tasklet
}


@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class A2 {
  private final JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
  ...

  @Bean
  public Job test2() {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("test2").start(step()).build();
  }

  ... step, tasklet
}
```

No matter what value is set in job.names, the test2 method of class A2 is always executed.

parameter argument is that
--spring.batch.job.names=test1 => executed test2 method and
--spring.batch.job.names=test2 => executed test2 method

if the A2 class is annotated(/* */), then test1 method is executed successfully.

what's the cause?

Comment: The bean will always be created that doesn't mean the job is actually being executed.

Answer (score 0):

i found the cause
in my case, @Bean step method name is same for two jobs.. T_T